# Why does Eigendecomposition of a matrix change the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, noncommutative-algebra, change-of-basis

I've been wrapping my head around eigendecomposition and i have stumbled onto something that seems to be confusing.

Given Matrix Transformation $$A = \begin{bmatrix}5&2&0\\2&5&0\\4&-1&4\end{bmatrix}$$ and Input Matrix $$Q = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1\\1&0&1\\1&1&5\end{bmatrix}$$

I Extracted Lambda diagonal Transformation $$\Lambda = \begin{bmatrix}7&0&0\\0&4&0\\0&0&3\end{bmatrix}$$

Formula for eigendecomposition: $$A = Q\Lambda ^{-1}$$  This means:

1. Multiply Matrix $Q$ by $\Lambda$ Transformation ($Q\Lambda$), which means this matrix would be scaled based on the given inputs.
2. Then multiply by inverse of Matrix $Q$ ($Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$)

**But,** everything must now be back to the origin since a transformation multiply by an inverse transformation $Q^{-1}$ cancels each other out and produces identity matrix.

Why is the resulting matrix equal to $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}5&2&0\\2&5&0\\4&-1&4\end{smallmatrix}\right]$?

\begin{align*}
(QQ^{-1})\Lambda&=(\text{Identity Matrix})(\Lambda) \\
&=\Lambda
\end{align*}  Then lambda matrix should be the answer, right?

Comment: This site uses MathJax and Markdown to format its content.  (There's a help button labeled "?" that elaborates on how to use markdown in the editor; it has a link to MathJax help too I believe.)  Please use them in future posts.

Answer (score 1):

Matrix multiplication is not commutative: $Q\Lambda Q^{-1} \neq QQ^{-1}\Lambda$ in general.

Comment: but why, im thinking right shear then scale then left shear = scaled origin | right shear then left shear then scaled = scaled origin. I'm still confused

Comment: do you know any website where i could visually see the 3d matrix transformation, it's kinda weird that i couldn't find any

Comment: @iZner You would be right if it happened that all the diagonal entries of $\Lambda$ were the same. They are not though, so $\Lambda$ is not a uniform scaling; it acts differently on each component.